# Electrons diffusion in gas with present of electric field

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, radiation, particle-detectors

For research purposes, I am looking for a way to calculate how far the electrons "spread" perpendicularly to the electric field in a chamber of gas.

For example, if a beam of alpha particles ionize the gas in a chamber and leave a track of electron-postive ion pairs, is there a way to calculate how far the electrons move away from the point of ionization (perpendicular to the electric field). Note: also present in the gas chamber is an electric field, so the electrons and positive ions would move in opposite direction. I am reading W. R. Leo's Techniques for Nuclear and Particles Physics Experiments for hints on how to calculate this, but I haven't found any mention of this yet. The closest thing I found was about electron diffusion with the absent of an electric field. Please point me to articles, book chapters, equations, or links regarding information of this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one can see;  
Longitudinal and transverse diffusion of electrons in high-pressure xenon 
H. Kusano,a  J.A.M. Lopes,b,c M. Miyajimaa and N. Hasebea a
a Research Institute for Science and Engineering, Waseda University, Shinjuku, Tokyo 169-8555, Japan 
bDepartment of Physics, University of Coimbra, 3004-516 Coimbra, Portugal 
c Instituto Superior de Engenharia de Coimbra, 3030-199 Coimbra, Portugal E-mail: hiroki-kusano@akane.waseda.jp 
  <http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-0221/8/01/C01028/pdf>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer in the W. R. Leo's Techniques for Nuclear and Particles Physics Experiments. The equations that I needed are Eq. 6.18
$D=\frac1 3 v \lambda $ and Eq. 6.46 $\sigma=\sqrt{2Dx/\mu E}$.